# The Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm on the same object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Was looking through the Vue.js source code and faced with controversial `if` statement. It's the part that defines reactive setter for a property.

```
if (newVal === value || (newVal !== newVal && value !== value)) {
  return
}
```

Have checked this [strict equality](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6) description and still cannot understand when such a comparison can be useful.

```
(newVal !== newVal && value !== value)
```

Comment: This is part of the issues/4236 on github read it here  https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4236

Comment: thanks @Gildas.Tambo. it's the exact answer on the question.

Answer (score 2):

`(newVal !== newVal && value !== value)` would be true if both `newVal` and `value` are `NaN`.

`(newVal === value)` on the other hand would be false, even if they are both `NaN`.

Comment: just out of interest, doesn't it simpler and more clear to just check on `NaN`?

Comment: Yes, there is a function that exactly does that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Comment: The function `isNaN` has a misleading name. It does not just check for `NaN`. e.g. `isNaN('x')` would be `true`. See also `Object.is`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is

Comment: @skirtle, this is true and it's mentioned in mdn: `The function should be interpreted as answering the question, "is this value, when coerced to a numeric value, an IEEE-754 'Not A Number' value?"`

Comment: @ElAoutarHamza My point being that the example given in this answer is currently wrong, you can't just use `isNaN` to replace the existing code. You would also need to use a `typeof` check, which is why the idiom `value === value` is typically used instead.